# How to include dependencies from git in stack build?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm building a Haskell project that depends on a project available in git, but not published in Hackage. What is the correct way of doing that?

I found the following solution online. Add the to `stack.yaml` in the base directory of my project:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location:
    git: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack.git
    commit: master
```

However I get the error:
`Aeson exception: Error in $.packages[1]: failed to parse field 'packages': expected Text, encountered Object`
Which suggests to me that packages doesn't take objects like that. Only names. So how do I do this?

Comment: Such dependencies should be specified as [`extra-deps`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-deps). The syntax you use isn't supported any more.

Comment: Thank you @sjakoby, is the syntax for extra-deps the same one?

Comment: The documentation I linked to contains examples of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Santiago, I wouldn't mind if you'd create the answer yourself.